# img src returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I am new to JS and don't understand why the image in my program isn't changing. all the variables work fine. Here is the snippet

```
function nextset(){
    var q = document.getElementById("i").src; //gets img src
    var w = document.getElementById("a").src; //gets img src
    var e = q.lastIndexOf("/"); 
    var r = w.lastIndexOf("/");
    var t = q.slice(0, e+1); 
    var a = parseInt(q.slice(e+1, -4));
    var b = parseInt(w.slice(r+1, -4)); 
    if (a < 23) {
        var c = (a + 2).toString();
        var d = (b + 2).toString();
        var e = ".jpg";
        var f = t.concat(c, e); //returns new img directory
        var g = t.concat(d, e); //returns new img directory
        q.src = f; //sets img
        w.src = g; //sets img
        console.log(q.src);
    }
    else {
        algo();
    }
}
```

All the images are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg,4.jpg, till 24.
This a really weird way of doing this and I know that also if anyone knows a better way that would be better.

Comment: In your code you start using `q` and `w` as strings, then you later start using them as HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `q` variable does not contain the DOM img element but the src of that element. So, when you're setting `q.src` you are actually doing this `document.getElementById("i").src.src` which does not make sense. You can extract the DOM element in a separate variable.

Also `parseInt` is smart enough so even if you do `parseInt("12.jpg")` it will return the number `12`, so you dont need to do `q.slice(e + 1, -4)` instead this is fine `q.slice(e + 1)`

```js
function nextset() {
  var qDOM = document.getElementById("i");
  var q = document.getElementById("i").src // https://images.test.com/12.jpg
  var e = q.lastIndexOf("/"); // 23
  var t = q.slice(0, e + 1); // https://images.test.com/
  var a = parseInt(q.slice(e + 1)); // 12
  if (a < 23) {
    var c = (a + 1).toString(); // 13
    var e = ".jpg";
    var f = t.concat(c, e); // https://images.test.com/13.jpg
    qDOM.src = f;
    console.log(qDOM.src);
  } else {
    algo();
  }
}

nextset()
```

```html
<img src="https://images.test.com/12.jpg" alt="" id="i">
```

Also, I would suggest you to store the current image index in a variable and then incrementing it, it would make your task much easier. Take a look at the code snippet below:

```js
const baseURL = "https://images.test.com/";
let currentImg = 1
const imgEl = document.getElementById("i");

function nextImg() {
  currentImg += 1;
  if (currentImg <= 24) {
    imgEl.src = baseURL + currentImg
  }else {
    // Do Something
  }
}

nextImg();
console.log(imgEl.src);
nextImg();
console.log(imgEl.src);
nextImg();
console.log(imgEl.src);
```

```html
<img src="https://images.test.com/1.jpg" alt="" id="i"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `src` of HTML element.
Something like that :

```
q = document.getElementById("i"); // Select just the element
  ...
q.src = f; // set the source of image
```